# How did I exceed the reputation cap today from only upvotes?

Tags: bug, reputation, voting, up-votes, reputation-cap

Today, I received +201 reputation from only upvotes, exceeding the [daily reputation limit of +200](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/188803).

[image: Screenshot of Deltik's reputation changes today]

This shouldn't be possible according to [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help) » [Reputation & Moderation](https://superuser.com/help/reputation) » [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from the combination of upvotes, downvotes and suggested edits.

How did some upvote 4 hours after I hit the limit change my reputation by +1?

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you downvoted another answer, or had something else happened that made you lose 1 reputation. This "gap" is filled by a later upvote on your answer.

Comment: I did downvote an answer yesterday, but not today.  In [my account reputation overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnWHh.png), this is correctly accounted for, but I did actually receive a net of +201 today.

Comment: @Deltik if you downvote an answer that was subsequently deleted then that "cost" would be refunded once the answer was deleted. Hence you lost a point yesterday and gained it back today.

Comment: @Mokubai: To be clear, I downvoted 2 answers yesterday for -2 reputation.  One of the answers was deleted yesterday, which correctly added +1 the same day.  I can see no activity to account for the +1 today.